# Get Sharepoint 2013 List Items data from certain fields with javascript and REST

Tags: javascript, json, rest, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to get list item data from certain columns(fields) from a certain list.

From what I understand I need the InternalName of the fields I want to pull list data from.

EDITED to include $expand to get both Field and Item information in one REST response:

EDITED to include the loop I'm currently using to create  options. I'm storing all the data in the Value, separating with ?'s and splitting the data to an HTML table when selected.

```
function execCrossDomainRequest() { 
    var executor; 

    executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync( 
        { 
            url: appweburl + 
                "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('Weights%20and%20Thickness')" +
                "?$select=Fields,Items&$expand=Fields,Items&@target='" + 
                hostweburl + "'", 
            method: "GET", 
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, 
            success: onDataReturned, 
            error: onError 
        } 
    ); 
} 

function onDataReturned(data) { 
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body); 
    var resultsFields = jsonObject.d.Fields.results;
    var resultsItems = jsonObject.d.Items.results;
    var calculateHTML = '';

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
     calculateHTML = calculateHTML + 
        "<option value='" + results[i].mvof + "?" + results[i].oc4d + "?" + results[i].ngot + "?" + 
        results[i].iv4s + "?" + results[i].j6i7 + "?" + results[i].OData__x006c_yg2 + "?" + 
        results[i].OData__x006f_po9 + "'>" + 
        results[i].Title + 
        "</option>"; 
} 
    document.getElementById("selectPieceDropdown").innerHTML = calculateHTML;
}
```

I only want to display the data in the movf, oc4d, ngot, iv4s, and j6i7 fields of the Items results. There are actually ~20 more fields with each Items result but I removed them for brevity.
My JSON response:

```
{
    d: {
        __metadata: {...}-
        Fields: {
            results: [64]
            0:  {...}-
            1:  {...}-
            2:  {...}-
            3:  {...}-
            4:  {...}-
            5:  {...}-
            6:  {...}-
            7:  {
                __metadata: {...}-
                InternalName: "mvof"
                StaticName: "mvof"
                Title: "Thickness"
            }
        }
        Items: {
            results: [32]
            0:  {
                Title: "#10 - Regular"
                mvof: 0.178
                oc4d: 1.96
                ngot: null
                iv4s: null
                j6i7: null
                OData__x006c_yg2: null
                OData__x006f_po9: null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How am I able to get the InternalName of a field, and then access that fields data from the Items results? I have tried:
`var internalThickness = resultsFields[7].InternalName;`
Then trying to use that:
`resultsItems.internalThickness` returned 'undefined'

Thank you, I've already learned a lot from the responses here, and the links to documentation. I'm just having trouble piecing together this one.